# Access variables in another class xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
//In class2.m File,

 HelloWorldLayer myHelloWorldLayer = [[HelloWorldLayer alloc]init];
 myHelloWorldLayer.myInt =100;
        NSLog(@"%i",myHelloWorldLayer.myInt);

//In HelloWorldLayer.h
int _myInt;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) int myInt;


//In HelloWorldLayer.m
@synthesize myInt= _myInt;

NSLog(@"%i",self.myInt);
```

When i run HelloWorld Layer, output is 0. I changed scene to class2 file and changed myInt to 100 and the output is 100. But when i replace scene back to HelloWorldLayer output is 0 again instead of 100. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear? Do you need to change the value of one  instance of a class, or do you want that value to be the same for all instances of that class?

Comment: I want to change myInt in HelloWorldLayer to 100.

Comment: I understand that part. What I do not understand is if you want that to be for all layers you make of that type, or just one of those layers you make.

Comment: I want that to be for all layers i make of that type. Like all layers should read myInt as 100 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// in HelloWorldLayer.h
// these are static variables. 
// You would reference them like so: 
// HelloWorldLayerStatic.myInt = x;
static struct { 
   int myInt; 
} HelloWorldLayerStatic;
```

Then, when you would refer to `self.myInt` or `myLayer.myInt`, you would refer to `HelloWorldLayerStatic.myInt`. It's a little bit of a hack, but it works.

Comment: May i know what is wrong with my code too? Thanks. I searched many answers and this method is supposed to work.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with your code, but when you use replaceScene with a new scene every time, you create a new instance of the scene, which thus replaces the instance variables, clearing `myInt` back to 0.

Comment: Also, please be sure to up vote and accept the answer if you can.